# Deep Query with Firebase

Tags: database, angular, firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database

I need help to query the a list of assessments with various classID's assigned to them.  This classID is a list of multiple classes and so far I've been trying thing like the below:

```
    var ref = firebase.database().ref(app.dbStrings.ASSESSMENTS).child('classID');

    return ref.once('value').then(function(data){
            console.log("Assessment Data: " + JSON.stringify(data.val()));
            return data;
    }
```

But this just gets the entire Assessments document.  Its been driving me crazy with how to use the firebase DB API to query deep objects like this.  See the image below for more detail in the DB structure.  I hope I'm not thinking too much in a relational way than a document way. [Database picture here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBebK.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could query the data in the frontend, but this depends on how much data you're expecting to have. Just by using the native js `.filter` method.

But in general, I would recommend you to avoid what you call "deep queries". Try to make your database structure more flatten. For example, save the `classID` as a key and access it directly.